# Index in v-for not reactive in <vs-collapse> component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using [vuesax](https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/) library and in that library there is one component called as `<vs-collapse>` for developing accordions.

I am populating those accordions dynamically using `v-for`

```vue
<vs-collapse accordion type="border">
    <vs-collapse-item v-for="(std, index) in stds" :key="'std'+std.id">
        <div slot="header" @click="loadStructure(index, std.id)">
            {{ std.std_roman }}
        </div>
    </vs-collapse-item>
</vs-collapse>
```

And while opening an accordion, I am calling a function `loadStructure()` accepting `index` from `v-for`

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            stds: [],
            fees_types: [],
            fees_installments: [],
            current_open_index: null,
            current_std_open: null,
            fees_structure: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadStructure(index, std_id) {
            if (this.current_open_index != index) {
                this.current_open_index = index;


                window.axios
                    .post("/api/fees/structure", {
                        std_id: std_id
                    }, {
                        headers: fetchAuthHeaders()
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (true == isResponseValid(response, this.$vs)) {
                            this.fees_structure = response.data.data;
                        }
                    })

            } else {
                this.current_open_index = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is whenever I click any accordion, the corresponding index is not updated sometimes in the function `loadStructure()` hence my model `fees_installments` is also not updated.

In short, the index sometimes works perfect and sometimes it takes the old index in my function.

If you need more code then just ask me, I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue you are facing. The above code works fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/50v2awnu/ Can you update the jsfiddle with your code? So that I can understand the issue?

Comment: I have updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c63vk40g/, I added a `current_index` and try to toggle the accordions, current_index will not get updated

Comment: It works only when you click on the "name" ex: "domain_0" . It is because the click is not on the whole div. Try to inspect the element and you will see.

Comment: So how can I apply @click event to whole div ?

Comment: Not possible as the Vuesax will replace whatever you do. Anyways above solution does not work only when user clicks the arrow. As of now, I do not have solution for this.

Comment: @Pradeepb I appreciate you, thanks for the help.